# RethinkDB filtering Object Array

Tags: r, rethinkdb, reql

I'm new to rethinkdb and I wanted to filter something like... **get all with Kiwi or Strawberry as preferred fruit**

```
{
    "id":  "65dbaa34-f7d5-4a25-b01f-682032fc6e05" ,
    "fruits": {
        "favorite":  "Mango" ,
        "preferred": [
                        "Kiwi" ,
                        "Watermelon"
                    ]
    }
}
```

I tried something like this after reading `contains` doc:

```
r.db('appname').table('food')
 .filter(r.row('fruits').contains(function(doc) {
   return doc('preferred').contains('Kiwi');
 }))
```

And I'm getting a `e: Cannot convert OBJECT to SEQUENCE in:` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```js
r.db('appname').table('food')
  .filter((row) => { 
    r.or( // Returns true if any of the following are true
      row('fruits')('preferred').contains('Kiwi'),
      row('fruits')('preferred').contains('Strawberry')
    )   
  });
```

You should know as well, that you can create your own index that calculates this for you, then you'd be able to do a [`.getAll`](https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/get_all/) query using your custom index and return all documents that fit this constraint very quickly.

Lastly, for something that would also work but is probably less efficient on large arrays:

```js
r.db("appname").table('food')
  .filter((row) => {
    return row('fruits')('preferred').setIntersection(['Kiwi', 'Strawberry']).count().gt(0) 
  })
```

Comment: Thank you upon testing, this worked :). The only catch on this solution is if "fruits.preferred" form is not consistent e.g if it's "fruits": "" when no favorite and preferred is set. The query will produce an error. Do you have a technique for such scenarios? Or just having an empty fruits: {favorite: "", preferred: []} the solution?

Comment: I figured it out. I need to use hasFields. :)